# Sending SSL HTTP request from Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, delphi, ssl

i'm having the problem only in the version of windows, server 2012 R2. when i send an SSL GET request, i dont receive anything, not even an error message. i dont know if its compatibility of DLLs problem or what,  i tried every single one of these versions : https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ . maybe its the problem in my code ?

```
procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
        LJSONArray : TJSONArray;
        Temp : TStrings;
        IdSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
        lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
        K : Boolean;
        pw : PwideChar;
    begin
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure   () var  I :Integer;
        begin
          try
               Temp := TStringList.Create;
              lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
              IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);
              lHTTp.ReadTimeout := 60000;
              IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_1;
              IdSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmClient;
              lHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSL;
              lHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
              LJSONArray := System.JSON.TJSONArray.Create;
              lhttp.Request.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8';
              lHTTP.Request.Host := 'baas.kinvey.com';
              lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Connection'] := 'Keep-Alive';
              lHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] :=  'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
              LHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
              lHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Embarcadero RESTClient/1.0';
              Reply := lhttp.Get('https://baas.kinvey.com/appdata/kid_xxxxxTEst/');
              LJSONArray :=  TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Reply, True) as TJSONArray;
                 for I := 0 to LJSONArray.Count -1 do
                      begin
                            Temp.Add(LJSonArray.Items[I].GetValue<string>('KEY'));
                      end;
                LJSONArray.Free;
                             K := False;
                             PW := pChar(Temp.text);
                             K := ExistWordInString(PW,'YES',[soWholeWord,soDown]);
                           if K = True then
                           begin
                              TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
                                        procedure ()
                                          begin
                                              Left:=(Screen.Width-Width)  div 2;
                                        end);
                                end;
                           if K = False then
                           begin
                              TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
                                        procedure ()
                                        begin
                                        Form5.Caption := '';
                                        end);
                                        end;
            except on E :exception do
                  begin
                    TThread.Synchronize (TThread.CurrentThread,
                      procedure ()
                      begin
                      memo1.lines.add(E.Message);
                      end);
                  end;
                end;
     end).Start;
    end;
```

Note : the code works in any other machine except Win server 2012 R2

Comment: So I wonder if it is an SSL issue or a threading issue.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately i dont have Windows Server 2012 R2,   i tried Amazon's 2012 R2 free server i it worked, it only happens in some VPSs. @ChrisReynolds

Comment: `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` indicates that the SSL implementation uses OpenSSL and not Schannel SSL implementation. Therefore there should be no difference on Windows 2012 Server R2. May be on that specific server the OpenSSL libraries are missing if they are not statically linked or the firewall is blocking the request.

Comment: Which version of Indy are you using exactly? You have to be getting SOMETHING from it. Either `TIdHTTP.Get()` will return a response from the server, or it will raise an exception on error, or it will simply block the calling thread until timeout if there is no network activity at all. Which is it? You need to debug your code. If you can't run the code in a debugger because you don't hq e the OS in question, then you need more logging, sniff the network traffic, etc.